# in react-router, "/path1" works, but "/path1/path2" renders nothing

Tags: react-router, react-router-v4

I'm freaking out, here's the gist

```
import * as React from 'react'
import { BrowserRouter, Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom';

class App extends React.Component{ 
  ...
  render(){
    return (
        <BrowserRouter>
          <div>
            <div>Header</div>

            <Switch>
              <Route path="/path1" render={()=>(<div>path1</div>)} />
              <Route path="/path1/path2" render={()=>(<div>path1/path2</div>)} />
            </Switch>
          </div>
        </BrowserRouter>
    );
  }
}
```

when I access `/path1`, it renders correctly, but `path1/path2` renders nothing (even "Header" part), and console shows no errors. 
what am I doing wrong? I'm using v4 of react-router

Update
I tried adding `exact` on the first route but things don't change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Brunno and Davi, it turned out to be the problem of webpack-dev-server and its config. What was happening is, when I tested the routes I was hard reloading the browser, and webpack-dev-server wasn't handling the things well because of the config fault.

I had api fallback setting for SPA (`devServer { historyApiFallback: ... }`),
and it works for flat paths like `/path1` on its own, but for deeper paths like `/path1/path2/*...` to work, we need

```
<base href="/" />
```

in the head section of `index.html` (or whatever file the server renders)

See more in [gh issue](https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server/issues/333#issuecomment-326834151)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the `path="/path1"` is being triggered first when you try to access `/path1/path2`. And because you are using `<Switch>`, the second component doesn't render. In your case, try using `exact path`, as follows:

```
import React from 'react'
import { BrowserRouter, Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom';

class App extends React.Component {
  render(){
    return (
        <BrowserRouter>
          <div>
            <div>Header</div>

            <Switch>
              <Route exact path="/path1" render={()=>(<div>path1</div>)} />
              <Route path="/path1/path2" render={()=>(<div>path1/path2</div>)} />
            </Switch>
          </div>
        </BrowserRouter>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Also, I don't know if that was a typo, but each Route should be a `Route` component, and NOT `Router`.

This should make it work!

Comment: Thanks, but I actually tried adding exact on the first route, and double checked now but still everything is same.. (and yes Router was typo)

Comment: Hmm. I just checked this code I posted in a project here and it worked. Is your project code exactly the same as what you posted?

Comment: Also, your Route components are not being closed with `/>`in the example you gave. But I'm guessing that's also a typo. Hehe.

Comment: Yea removed the whole things and made the root component exactly like above.. okay i'll try rebooting webpack and stuff then try again

Comment: hm, rebooted webpack wacher and stuff but still the same.

Comment: That is really strange. I just pasted you corrected code and it works perfectly here. I can post my app structure on github if that would help! The only thing missing in your gist is the `export default App` but I guess you just didn't paste it here.

Comment: yea, got `export..` as well, and at least `/path1` is working. Thanks for the help, probably I'm missing something.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158441/discussion-between-brunno-vodola-martins-and-ryo).

Answer (score 0):

try changing the order of that the routes are in.

```
<Switch>
  <Route path="/path1/path2" render={()=>(<div>path1/path2</div>)} />
  <Route exact path="/path1" render={()=>(<div>path1</div>)} /></Switch>
```